# The simple android application i have created crushes as soon as i try to run it in android studio

Tags: android, xml

I am learning xml and this is all the 'code' my app executes when I run it.When I hit run in android studio and I get the following message unfortunately 'my app has suddenly stopped' accompanied by the following error messages in the event log,

> 1. Emulator: Warning: QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR points to non-existing path '/run/user/1000/snap.android-studio', please create
>      it with 0700 permissions. ((null):0, (null))
> 2. Emulator: pc_memory_init: above 4g size: 40000000

I have tried running the app on diferent virtual devices as well as my own android device.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/happy_birthday"
        android:text="@string/birthday"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dear_ian"
        android:layout_width="291dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/happy_birthday"
        android:layout_marginStart="-127dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/happy_birthday"
        android:text="@string/ian"
        android:textSize="30sp" />


    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/download"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/from_dennis"
        android:text="@string/dennis"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>
```

app should run but it does not

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue, as well as the complete [stack trace from the crash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23353174).

Answer (score 3):

Your application is not working not because of this. What is written in the log is only a warning. You can correct this warning by creating the necessary folder. To do this, write in the terminal linux:

```
mkdir /run/user/1000/snap.android-studio
```

Answer (score 2):

I stopped getting the **Emulator: pc_memory_init: above 4g size: 40000000** error after decreasing the RAM on the AVD below 4G:

1. From the main menu, click: `Tools > AVD Manager`
2. Click the **pencil** icon (Edit this AVD) under `Actions` for the target Virtual Device.
3. Click `Show Advanced Settings`
4. Set `RAM` to a value less than 4G (for instance, 3072MB)
5. Click `Finish`, then `Run` your app!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

- **From file menu: Invalidate cache and restart**
- **Increase Android Studio memory limit**
- **Run as Administrator**

Also try posting the logcat / MainClass